# Вечное выполнение UglifyJS WebStorm FileWatcher

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Всем привет. Решил настроить автосжатие своих скриптов  и у меня почти получилось. При внесении изменений в файл он сжимается с помощью UglifyJS. Но проблема в том, что он это делает постоянно по 1-2 раза в сек, при этом никаких ошибок не возникает. В чем может быть проблема?

Использую WebStorm 2017.2

[image: Настройки FileWatcher]

Comment: можно и показать конфиги, настройки и то, какой код повешан для обработки

Comment: Прошу прощения, добавил...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась. Дело в том, что при сжатии скрипта, UglifyJS создает новый js файл, который отслеживается FileWatcher и к нему снова применяется UglifyJS.
Решение:

1. Отслеживать изменения файлов только в одном каталоге, а сжимать их в другой.
2. Добавить префикс *-min.js, и через регулярные выражения отфильтровать файлы с этим префиксом.